# SQL parameterized query, where you can also pass "all"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

Having a tough time finding any info on this out there, but is it possible to pass an "all" or "*" like value to a parameterized query's `?`, so as to get all results:

```
AND st.SomeColumn = ?
```

where ? would be RETURN ALL MATCHES? So then you could in theory pass any possible individual matches or retrieve all without some string concatenation shenanigans (which I know is totally possible and is my plan B).

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the query you want to write.  From your description it is really hard to tell what you want.

Comment: Instead of using `?` why don't you use named and strongly-typed parameters? Or (gasp) a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to build this into the query logic.  One simple way is (if the columns contain no `NULL` values) is to pass in the parameter as `NULL` and do:

```
 st.SomeColumn = COALESCE(?, st.SomeColumn)
```

Otherwise:

```
 (st.SomeColumn = ? OR (? IS NULL))
```

This requires passing the parameter twice -- which is why named parameters are handy.